# How to deploy highly iterative updates

Tags: python, macos, deployment, ubuntu, rsync

I have a set of binary assets (swf files) each about 150Kb in size. I am developing them locally on my home computer and I want to periodically deploy them for review. My current strategy is:

1. Copy the .swf's into a transfer directory that is also a hg (mercurial) repo.
2. `hg push` the changes to my slicehost VPN
3. `ssh` onto my slicehost VPN

   - `cd` to my transfer directory and `hg up`
   - `su www` and `cp` the changed files into my public folder for viewing.

I would like to automate the process. Best case scenario is something close to:

1. Copy the .swf's into a "quick deploy" directory
2. Run a single local script to do all of the above.

I am interested in:

- advice on where to put passwords since I need to `su www` to transfer files into the public web directories.
- how the division of responsibility between local machine and server is handled.

I think using rsync is a better tool than hg since I don't really need a revision history of these types of changes. I can write this as a python script, a shell script or however is considered a best practice.

Eventually I would like to build this into a system that can handle my modest deployment needs. Perhaps there is an *open-source deployment system* that handles this and other types of situations? I'll probably roll-my-own for this current need but long term I'd like something relatively flexible.

**Note:** My home development computer is OS X and the target server is some recent flavour of Ubuntu. I'd prefer a python based solution but if this is best handled from the shell I have no problems putting it together that way.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid `su www` I see two easy choices.

- make a folder writable to you and readable by www's group in some path that the web-server will be able to serve, then you can rsync to that folder from somewhere on your local machine.
- put your public ssh key in www's authorized_keys and rsync to the www user (a bit less security in some setups perhaps, but not much, and usually more convenient).

working around `su www` by putting your or its password in some file would seem far less secure.

A script to invoke `"rsync -avz --partial /some/path www@server:some/other/path"` should be quick to write in python (although I do not python well).

Comment: rsync with authorized ssh keys proved to be a good temporary solution when run as a simple shell script. I will eventually want something  that can handle some logical file system manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at all comfortable in Python, I recommend [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) for automated deployment scripts.

In addition to group permissions or ssh-ing as www (with key-based auth), a third solution to the permissions issue would be to add your user to /etc/sudoers and use sudo (you can specify the exact command your user is allowed to use sudo for, so you can make the security implications minimal).

Comment: I like Python and the documentation of the project looks decent. Thanks.